# authentification with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, authentication

i need to modified this plunker code : plnkr.co/edit/Mvrte4?p=preview

i need to remove the user role , and all of user accede to the same page

if possible make the modified code in tow page

- page 1 : index.html content login form
- page 2 : home.html content logout btn

this is list of user who can login to home.html

```
    [{  "username": "user1","password": "pass1" }, {"username": "user2","password": "pass2" }, {"username": "user3","password": "pass3"}, {"username": "user4","password": "pass4"}]
```

my plunker : plnkr.co/edit/fplol0FFpGkLZC3ZdgKX?p=preview

this is image schema what i need
[image]

please please someone help me

Answer (score 1):

http://plnkr.co/edit/TGnjdh1BIfpTx48OKVtT?p=preview

- You need to include AngularJS as a JavaScript dependency in your index.html.
- You need to include an `ng-app` directive and specify a module (I used `myApp`).
- You need to make your password element of `type` `password`.
- I broke everything up into directives - Index calls `<main />`, which calls `<home />` and `<login />`.
- `ng-if` creates an isolated scope so I used `controllerAs` and `vm` to pass the data correctly between the `<home />` and `<login />` directives.
- I added `ng-model` to the input elements for two-way binding; as the user interacts with the `<input />` elements, the values on the `$scope` stay up-to-date.
- I used `{{ }}` to display the username.
- I used `$http` to get the the username and passwords you put in a `.json` file.
- You'll want to do username/password validation on the server and not download them all to the client like you're currently doing.
- You'll want to use an authentication framework so you don't have to worry about things like encrypting the user's password on the server.
- You misspelled Welcome and Logout.
- I should be setting `$scope.password` to `undefined` inside the `logout` `function`; I missed that.
- If you wanted a solution with only (2) .html files like you asked in your question (I would suggest splitting everything up into components, instead), here you go: http://plnkr.co/edit/MdEu7wo0T9gGiLUrHkKc?p=preview